# Adjusting percentage decimals for a bar plot with facet_grid()

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, percentage

I have the following line:

```
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x= cyl)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = vs), stat = "count") + geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..prop..), ymax= ..prop..), stat = "count", vjust = -0.5) +  theme_classic() + ylab("Count") + facet_grid(vs ~ .) + ylim(0, 15)
```

which gives this plot. This is a plot where I want to keep the count integers on the y-axis, but I want the percentages displayed above each bar.

[image]

I would like to edit the number of decimals over each bar plot. However, when using the line below:

```
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x= cyl)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = vs), stat = "count") + geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(round((..count..)/sum(..count..),1)), ymax= ((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat="count",  vjust = -.25) + theme_classic() + ylab("Count") + facet_grid(vs ~ .) + ylim(0, 15)
```

The percentages are now off (see below), displaying the percentages for the whole plot, and not the separated facets. Is there a way to round the percentages without compromising the numbers?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an accuracy option in scales::percent:

```
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x= cyl)) + 
geom_bar(aes(fill = vs), stat = "count") + 
geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..prop..,accuracy=2)), 
stat = "count", vjust = -0.5) +  
theme_classic() + ylab("Count") + facet_grid(vs ~ .) + ylim(0, 15)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `accuracy = 2` in the `scales::percent` function:

```
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x= cyl)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = vs), stat = "count") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..prop.., accuracy = 2), ymax= ..prop..), stat = "count", vjust = -0.5) + 
  theme_classic() + ylab("Count") + facet_grid(vs ~ .) + ylim(0, 15)
p1
```

Comment: You were less than 10 secs apart. But thank you nonetheless!